Can I use JetBrains Diagrams in my plugin
I'm new to plugin development in JetBrains and I'm currently working on a plugin aimed at visualizing code analysis through graphs. I've noticed that JetBrains provides robust graph visualization tools within their 'Diagrams' options.
I'm curious if there's a way to integrate or migrate my plugin to utilize these diagramming capabilities for visualizing new analyses and graphs that I'm attempting to add. Can I leverage this diagram platform to customize and visualize graphs based on my input for nodes and edges?
Any insights or guidance on how to integrate my plugin with the JetBrains diagram platform would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
I've been searching for information on this topic but haven't had any success yet.

yWorks is the provider of the core of the API that JetBrains is using in their IDEs. To my knowledge, the API that JetBrains provides (it's a wrapper around the yFiles for Java 2.x API) should be accessible to plugin developers, but I am unaware of the documentation for it. In a commercial context, it might be easier to just use the "real" and more modern yFiles API, directly, instead.
